# Sorting a list of values inside a dictionary using lambda

Tags: sorting, lambda, python-3.7

I was trying to sort a list of values, inside a dictionary. I have created a list like the following:

```
d= [
    {'make': 'Nokia', 'model': [100,300,200], 'color': 'Black'}, 
    {'make': 'Mi Max', 'model': [20,50,40], 'color': 'Gold'}, 
    {'make': 'Samsung', 'model':[5,4,3], 'color': 'Blue'}
   ]
```

Inside the outer list there are three dictionaries, which have their own keys and values. Here I want to sort the inner list. I am trying to get an output like:

```
[
 {'make': 'Samsung', 'model': [3, 4, 5], 'color': 'Blue'},
 {'make': 'Mi Max', 'model': [20, 40, 50], 'color': 'Gold'},
 {'make': 'Nokia', 'model': [100, 200, 300], 'color': 'Black'}
]
```

I am using lambda like the following but it is not giving me the expected output:

```
d.sort(key = lambda x: (x['model']))
```

Can someone please explain how can I reach to my inner list and sort it using lambda?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to sort both the dictionary (by minimum `model` value) and also the `model` list within the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to sort both.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort the `model` lists in each dict, you can just iterate over the list of dicts and sort them:

```
for o in d:
    o['model'].sort()
```

Output:

```
[
 {'make': 'Nokia', 'model': [100, 200, 300], 'color': 'Black'},
 {'make': 'Mi Max', 'model': [20, 40, 50], 'color': 'Gold'},
 {'make': 'Samsung', 'model': [3, 4, 5], 'color': 'Blue'}
]
```

If you *also* want to sort the top-level array by `model` values, you could then sort on (for example) the minimum `model` value:

```
d.sort(key=lambda o:min(o['model']))
```

Output:

```
[
 {'make': 'Samsung', 'model': [3, 4, 5], 'color': 'Blue'},
 {'make': 'Mi Max', 'model': [20, 40, 50], 'color': 'Gold'},
 {'make': 'Nokia', 'model': [100, 200, 300], 'color': 'Black'}
]
```